# VBA code needed to import text file data into excel sheet column wise

Tags: excel, vba

I have a text file containing some data as shown:
22343
4.3
Linux version

(Each data is on a newline in text file)

I need to import this data "Column-Wise" into an excel file
Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Unfortunately, this is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) for here. Can you provide some code? What else did you research and/or try? Please show your efforts first so that other people might help you out. Also, please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
Sub ImportFile()
    Close #1
    Open "C:\TestFolder\TestFile.txt" For Input As #1
    j = 1
     Do While Not EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, TextLine
            Cells(j, 1) = TextLine
            j = j + 1
        Loop
    Close #1
End Sub
```